# How to stop scan in HBase coprocessor

Tags: java, indexing, hbase, scanf

I am using HBase1.2.6 .In HBase table, I created an index table, so I can retrieve data with secondary index. The step is like this:

```
1. send a scan opration at client
2. parse the filter and create index table scan filter at coprocessor's prescannernext
3. get result set at at coprocessor's prescannernext
4. then stop scan and return result set
```

There is something wrong in my code, and I can not find out where it is.

After getting result set, the scan operation does not stop. After scan region, a couple of seconds are wasted.

How can I stop the scan operation at prescannernext?

Here is my code:

```
public boolean preScannerNext(final ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> e, final InternalScanner s,
        final List<Result> results, final int limit, final boolean hasMore) throws IOException {
    logger.info("result size: " + results.size());

    if (filterList != null) {
        List<Filter> li = filterList.getFilters();
        SingleColumnValueFilter sf = (SingleColumnValueFilter) li.get(0);
        byte[] family = sf.getFamily();
        byte[] qualifier = sf.getQualifier();
        byte[] startValue = sf.getComparator().getValue();
        byte[] endValue = ((SingleColumnValueFilter) li.get(1)).getComparator().getValue();
        String qualifierStr = new String(qualifier);
        String shortQualifier = qualifierStr.split("_", -1)[0].substring(0, 1).toLowerCase()
                + qualifierStr.split("_", -1)[1].substring(0, 1).toLowerCase();
        byte[] startKey = e.getEnvironment().getRegionInfo().getStartKey();
        if (startKey.length == 0) {
            logger.info("filterList first region");
            startKey = "00".getBytes();
        }
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        String scanPre = new String(startKey) + "|" + shortQualifier + "|";
        byte[] startRow = Bytes.add(scanPre.getBytes(), startValue);
        byte[] stopRow = Bytes.add(scanPre.getBytes(), endValue);
        logger.info("filterList scanPre: " + scanPre);
        logger.info("filterList startRow: " + startRow);
        logger.info("filterList stopRow: " + stopRow);
        scan.setStartRow(startRow);
        scan.setStopRow(stopRow);
        Region region = e.getEnvironment().getRegion();
        RegionScanner rs = region.getScanner(scan);
        info = "region scan";
        results.clear();
        try {
            while (true) {
                List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
                rs.next(cells);
                if (cells.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                if (cells.size() > 1) {
                    logger.info("filterList finde index to row: " + cells.size());
                }
                for (Cell cell : cells) {
                    String rk = new String(CellUtil.cloneRow(cell)).split("-", -1)[1];
                    Get get = new Get(rk.getBytes());
                    results.add(region.get(get));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            rs.close();
        }
        e.bypass();
        logger.info("filterList here pass scan");
        logger.info("filterList result size: " + results.size());
        filterList = null;
        return false;
    }

    e.bypass();
    logger.info("at last result size: " + results.size());
    logger.info(hasMore ? "1" : "0");
    return hasMore;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for check my grammar, my English is so poor。